# Combine several calculations on several variables

Tags: r

*This is my very first time here, I am coming from stackoverflow.com thanks to @r2evans.
So I apologize in advance if I don't follow all the rules.*

I wrote a code in `data.table`, doing what I am expected of it. It is not so complicated : mainly sum, group by, or some basic calculations.

But my real challenge here is called **performance**. Real datas contain millions of lines, and the calculations are made on dozens and dozens of columns.

Now, let me show you the code I wrote (with some options) :

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
library(microbenchmark)
library(tictoc)

n.row <- 1e5

foo <- data.table(id = 101:(101+n.row-1), 
                  crit = rep(c('fr', 'ca', 'al', 'se', 'is'), 5),
                  val_1 = round(runif(n.row, 0.5, 50), digits = 2),
                  val_2 = round(runif(n.row, 1, 20), digits = 0),
                  val_3 = round(runif(n.row, 1, 5), digits = 0),
                  eff = 28500,
                  num = sample(0:1,n.row, replace = TRUE),
                  num_2 = round(runif(n.row, 1, 10), digits = 1),
                  num_17 = round(runif(n.row, 1, 10), digits = 1),
                  num_69 = round(runif(n.row, 0, 1), digits = 2),
                  num_5 = round(runif(n.row, 10, 20), digits = 0),
                  cof = round(runif(n.row, 0.1, 2), digits = 5),
                  ToDo = rep(1, n.row),
                  grp_0 = "TOT",
                  grp_1 = sample(LETTERS[c(1,3)], n.row, replace = TRUE))


foo[, c("grp_2", "grp_3") := {
  grp_2 = fcase(grp_1 %in% LETTERS[c(1)], sample(LETTERS[c(5,8,9)], n.row, replace = TRUE),
                grp_1 %in% LETTERS[c(3)], sample(LETTERS[c(14,16)], n.row, replace = TRUE))
  
  grp_3 = fcase(grp_1 %in% LETTERS[c(1)], sample(LETTERS[c(20:23)], n.row, replace = TRUE),
                grp_1 %in% LETTERS[c(3)], sample(LETTERS[c(24:26)], n.row, replace = TRUE))
  
  list(grp_2, grp_3)
}]

# Calcul sd and qa
foo[, `:=` (
  sd = val_1 * cof,
  qa = fifelse(num == 1, val_2 * cof, val_3 * cof)
)]

foo1 <- copy(foo)
foo2 <- copy(foo)
foo3 <- copy(foo)

# calcul of qa_X
var.calc <- names(foo)[str_which(names(foo), "^num.\\d+$")]

# 1.1
for (j in var.calc){
  foo1[, paste0("qa_", str_extract(j, "\\d+$")) := qa * get(j)]
}

# 1.2
setDT(foo2)[, paste0("qa_", str_extract(var.calc, "\\d+$")) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x * qa), .SDcols = var.calc ]

# 1.3
for (j in var.calc) set(foo3, j = paste0("qa_", str_extract(j, "\\d+$")), value = foo3$qa * foo3[[j]])

# compare
mbm <- microbenchmark(
  Test.for = for (j in var.calc){ foo1[, paste0("qa_", str_extract(j, "\\d+$")) := qa * get(j)] },
  Test.set = setDT(foo2)[, paste0("qa_", str_extract(var.calc, "\\d+$")) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x * qa), .SDcols = var.calc ],
  Test.for.set = for (j in var.calc) set(foo3, j = paste0("qa_", str_extract(j, "\\d+$")), value = foo3$qa * foo3[[j]]),
  times = 20
)

mbm


# calcul by groups
var.grp <- names(foo)[str_which(names(foo), "^grp.\\d+$")]
var.calc.2 <- names(foo2)[str_which(names(foo2), "^(sd|qa)")]

# 2.1
for (j in var.grp) {
  for (k in var.calc.2) {
    foo1[, paste0("s.", k, "_", j) := sum(get(k)), by = get(j)]
  }
}

# 2.2
for (j in var.grp) {
  setDT(foo2)[, paste0("s.", var.calc.2, "_", j) := lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x)), .SDcols = var.calc.2, by = j ]
}
```

As I said, I am really looking for speed. So if anybody has some advice, some tips, another way to obtain the results, it would be very appreciable.

Many thanks.